# creating a responsive scroll transition with images

Tags: jquery, scroll, responsive

I'm working on a page where the content is broken into a couple of different sections. To the right, each section has an image associated with it. Instead of having a static image for each, I'm trying to have one fixed image that changes when you scroll to each section. I came across the following jquery code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
  var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
  }else{
    jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

That would change the class name of the image area and I can swap it out using css transitions. The problem is that the trigger is based on pixel distance from the top, which would change with different screen sizes due to the text flow changing. Is there a way I can set the trigger based on reaching the section? I was thinking if I had anchors with the subheads, that could trigger it, but what I've found is based on clicking a link, not scrolling.

Does anyone have a possible solution? Thanks

Comment: You can get the position of an element with `$(element).offset().top`.  Can you select the element easily?

Comment: Please share a codepen link of your work till now.